# .NET Remoting on Mono 2.10: Uri already in use

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, uri, .net-remoting

I am running Ubuntu 13.10, 64-bit or Ubuntu 12,32-bit and Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1.

I have an application developed in VS 2008 that uses .NET remoting. We are trying to run this on Ubuntu/Ubuntu Kylin now, but I am receiving the following error.

```
//some code is removed with Mono Migration Analyzer
RemotingConfiguration.Configure(Application.ExecutablePath + ".config");

RemotingConfiguration.CustomErrorsEnabled(false);               
// Create and marshal an object for remote invocation.
_RemotingServer = new RemotingServer();
//Register Client
_RemotingServer.KeepAliveClient = new delClientInfo(KeepAliveClient);
_RemotingServer.AddClient = new delClientInfo(AddClient);
_RemotingServer.RemoveClient = new delClientInfo(RemoveClient);

//Here <exception:uri already in use>
obj = RemotingServices.Marshal(this._RemotingServer, "RemotingServer");
```

causing exception:
System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Uri already in use:

```
<!--Remoting 设置-->
    <system.runtime.remoting>
        <customErrors mode="off"/>
        <application>

      <service>
                <wellknown mode="Singleton" objectUri="RemotingServer" type="EquipsLib.RemotingServer,EquipsLib" />
            </service>

      <channels>
                <channel name="MyChannel" port="8090" ref="http">
                    <serverProviders>
                        <provider ref="wsdl"/>
                        <formatter ref="binary" typeFilterLevel="Full"/>
                    </serverProviders>
                    <clientProviders>
                        <formatter ref="binary"/>
                    </clientProviders>
                </channel>
            </channels>
        </application>
    </system.runtime.remoting>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Did you try with the latest Mono 3.12 instead of this old version? You can get it at http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux

Comment: I try it  with the Mono 3.2.8 ,but the problem is still there.

Comment: 3.2.8 is not the latest version, 3.12 is.